# How do i include more than one property in group by key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Assume i have the following tables in DB

**Departments**

```
ID     Name
1      Engineering
2      Accounting
3      Sales
```

**Employees**

```
ID     Name   DeparmentId
1      Phill    1
2      moore    1
3      lucas    2
4      john     2
5      sophie   3
6      george   3
```

what i want to do is to group by `Employees` by `Deparments`. I know the standard method of grouping will group employees by either `departmentID` or `Department Name`. But i want is the grouping key must be an object having multiple properties (ID and Name). Is there away to do this? please provide me some code!

Comment: Implement `IEquatable interface`. Search for grouping by reference type.

Comment: @har07 mutiple columns will create an inner hierarchy but i dont want another herachy instead what i want is the each parent object (Deparmtnet) must have two properties (ID, name) so i can access the ID and Name in Ajax body

Answer (score 1):

You can use new keyword

```
from f in table
group f by new { f.id, f.name} into g
select ....
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but would be able to have a look at the comment i wrote to har07's reply